# unix domain stream sockets sending more data then it should be

Tags: c++, unix, sockets, iostream

I have two simple programs set up that share data through a unix domain socket. One program reads data out of a Queue and sends it to the other application. Before it is sent each piece of data is front-appended by four bytes with the length, if it is less then four bytes the left over bytes are the '^' symbol.

The client application then reads the first four bytes, sets a buffer to the appropriate size and then reads the rest. The problem that I'm having is that the first time through the message will be sent perfectly. Every other time after that there is extra data being sent so a message like "what a nice day out" would come out like "what a nice day out??X??". So I feel like a buffer is not being cleared correctly but I can't seem to find it.

Client code:

```
listen(sock, 5);
for (;;) 
{
    msgsock = accept(sock, 0, 0);
    if (msgsock == -1)
        perror("accept");
    else do 
    {
        char buf[4];
        bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
        if ((rval = read(msgsock, buf, 4)) < 0)
        perror("reading stream message");

        printf("--!%s\n", buf);

        string temp = buf;
        int pos = temp.find("^");
        if(pos != string::npos)
        {
            temp = temp.substr(0, pos);
        }

        int sizeOfString = atoi(temp.c_str());
        cout << "TEMP STRING: " << temp << endl;
        cout << "LENGTH " << sizeOfString << endl;
        char feedWord[sizeOfString];
        bzero(feedWord, sizeof(feedWord));

        if ((rval = read(msgsock, feedWord, sizeOfString)) < 0)
              perror("reading stream message");

          else if (rval == 0)
              printf("Ending connection\n");
          else
              printf("-->%s\n", feedWord);
              bzero(feedWord, sizeof(feedWord));
              sizeOfString = 0;
              temp.clear();
      } 
        while (rval > 0);
      close(msgsock);
  }
  close(sock);
  unlink(NAME);
```

Server Code

```
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mylock);
                string s;
                s.clear();
                s = dataQueue.front();
                dataQueue.pop();
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mylock);

                int sizeOfString = strlen(s.c_str());
                char sizeofStringBuffer[10];

                sprintf(sizeofStringBuffer, "%i", sizeOfString);
                string actualString = sizeofStringBuffer;
                int tempSize = strlen(sizeofStringBuffer);

                int remainder = 4 - tempSize;
                int x;
                for(x =0; x < remainder; x++)
                {
                    actualString = actualString + "^";
                }

                cout << "LENGTH OF ACTUAL STRING: " << sizeOfString << endl;

                actualString = actualString + s;

                cout << "************************" << actualString << endl;
                int length = strlen(actualString.c_str());

                char finalString[length];
                bzero(finalString, sizeof(finalString));
                strcpy(finalString, actualString.c_str());

                           if (write(sock, finalString, length) < 0)
                           perror("writing on stream socket");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than padding your packet length with '`^`', you'd be far better off just doing:

```
snprintf(sizeofStringBuffer, 5, "%04d", sizeOfString);
```

so that the value is 0 padded - then you don't need to parse out the '^' characters in the receiver code.

Please also edit out your debug code - there's only one `write()` in the current code, and it doesn't match your description of the protocol.

Ideally - split your sending routine into a function of its own.  You can also take advantage of `writev()` to handle coalescing the string holding the "length" field with the buffer holding the actual data and then sending them as a single atomic `write()`.

Untested code follows:

```
int write_message(int s, std::string msg)
{
     struct iovec iov[2];
     char hdr[5];

     char *cmsg = msg.c_str();
     int len = msg.length();

     snprintf(hdr, 5, "%04d", len);  // nb: assumes len <= 9999;

     iov[0].iov_base = hdr;
     iov[0].iov_len = 4;

     iov[1].iov_base = cmsg;
     iov[1].iov_len = len;

     return writev(s, iov, 2);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution for me but I'm a little confused with what to do with readv. On the reading side would I just set a buffer to the size of iov[0].iov_len and then fill that buffer with iov[1].iov_base?

Comment: in this case you can't use readv - you do need to read the four byte length field first, and then read the second buffer of the specified length.

Comment: Still doesn't fix the fundamental problem with the code in the question - which is that the string being read, is not null-terminated, and therefore the printf() will print the string, some of the stack up to the first null encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check return values of both `write` and `read` not only for `-1` but for short (less then requested) writes/reads. You also seem to just continue after printing an error with `perror` - do an `exit(2)` or something there.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First - on the Server side you are writing off the end of your array.

```
char finalString[length];
bzero(finalString, sizeof(finalString));
strcpy(finalString, actualString.c_str());
```

The `strcpy()` will copy `length+1` characters into `finalString` (character pull the null terminator).

Second (and most likely to be the problem) - on the client side you are not null terminating the string you read in, therefore the `printf()` will print your string, and then whatever is on the stack up to the point it hits a null.

Increase both buffers by one, and you should be in better shape.